# What does it mean by "number of permutations on n elements that are involutions"

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, definition

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telephone_number_(mathematics)

This is another question on telephone numbers.
As mentioned in this wikipedia article, telephone numbers are here defined as "the number of permutations on n elements that are involutions"
Can someone please explain what this means?
The article later says this:

*"Every pattern of pairwise connections between n subscribers defines an involution, a permutation of the subscribers that is its own inverse, in which two subscribers who are making a call to each other are swapped with each other and all remaining subscribers stay in place. Conversely, every possible involution has the form of a set of pairwise swaps of this type. Therefore, the telephone numbers also count involutions."*

I know the concept of an involution, and I know what permutations are, but I can't seem to understand this explanation.

Answer (score 1):

One involution on the numbers 1 to 6 is $(12)(35)$.
This represents 1 phoning 2, 3 phoning 5, and 4 and 6 not talking to anyone